# Xquery error with fn:substring-before

Tags: xpath, xquery

```
    <url>{substring-before(data($y/link[1]/@href),'&')}</url>
```

The error I get when trying to run this is

```
    No closing ';' found for entity or character reference
```

Anybody have any idea what's causing this error?

Answer (score 5):

In XQuery an ampersand within a string literal (and in certain other contexts) needs to be escaped as `&amp;`, just as it would be in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Kay is correct.  The "&" is illegal by itself in XML.  It is always to be accompanied by an entity.  Examples include & < >, etc.
If you think that your search won't work because you are searching for "&" instead of "&", that is not proper thinking.  As a human, try to translate in your head that "&" really looks like "&" to the XML parser.  Doing this will work:

```
<url>{substring-before(data($y/link[1]/@href),'&amp')}</url>
```